# is there a way i can get www-data as the owner from nodjes without having to use the uid 33 in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, linux

I have this code which works fine but I want it to be www-data instead of the uid 33. it's a Linux system which means uid of 33 is www-data but I think that might not be always the case.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const stats = await fs.stat('/some-file-path');

const owner = stats.uid; //owner is 33 for www-data but is there a way I can get www-data itself?
const mode = stats.mode;

const isOwnerWwwData = owner === 33 && mode === 33204;
```

Comment: This https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383811 ?

Comment: @deEr. i can't find any answer there

Comment: This: https://nodejs.org/api/permissions.html#process-based-permissions ?

Comment: Please note that `www-data` is typically the owner on Debian/Ubuntu based systems, but not on e.g. Redhat or Fedora, which means that you swapped one inconsistent approach with another (though your idea widens it from 1 (or a small subset of Debian based systems) to all of those, marked improvement!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using this code

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const filePath = 'file-path';

try {
    const stdout = execSync(`stat -c %U ${filePath}`, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    const username = stdout.trim();
    console.log(`The file '${filePath}' is owned by ${username}`);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error executing command: ${error.message}`);
}
```